# How to zoom inside a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

this plot shows the voltage course lines of a simulated neuron:

[image: plot 1]

i would like to place a zoom in plot in the upper right corner so that you can see the current fluctuations of the lines better (the scale here is such that you can hardly see them)

attached the code for the plot

> factor to define voltage-amplitude heights
>
> ```
> v_amp_factor = 1/(50)
>
> ##### distances between lines and x-axis
> offset = np.cumsum(distance_comps_middle)/meter
> offset = (offset/max(offset))*10
> plt.close(plot_name)
> voltage_course = plt.figure(plot_name)
> for ii in comps_to_plot:
>     plt.plot(time_vector/ms, offset[ii] - v_amp_factor*(voltage_matrix[ii, :]-V_res)/mV, "#000000")
> plt.yticks(np.linspace(0,10, int(length_neuron/mm)+1),range(0,int(length_neuron/mm)+1,1))
> plt.xlabel('Time/ms', fontsize=16)
> plt.gca().invert_yaxis() # inverts y-axis => - v_amp_factor*(.... has to be written above
>
> ##### no grid
> plt.grid(False)
> plt.savefig('plot_name', dpi=600)
> plt.show(plot_name)
> ```

```
parameter description: 
   Parameters
    ----------
    plot_name : string
        This defines how the plot window will be named.
    time_vector : list of time values
        Vector contains the time points, that correspond to the voltage values
        of the voltage matrix.
    voltage_matrix : matrix of membrane potentials
        Matrix has one row for each compartment and one columns for each time
        step. Number of columns has to be the same as the length of the time vector
    comps_to_plot : vector of integers
        This vector includes the numbers of the compartments, which should be part of the plot.
    distance_comps_middle : list of lengths
        This list contains the distances of the compartments, which allows that
        the lines in the plot are spaced according to the real compartment distances
    length_neuron : length
        Defines the total length of the neuron.
    V_res : voltage
        Defines the resting potential of the model.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes

# let's plot something similar to your stuff
t = np.linspace(-5, 5, 2001)
y = np.exp(-20*t**2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(14):
    start = 900-10*i
    ax.plot(t[1000:1500], -5*y[start:start+500]/(1+i*0.3)+i, 'k')
ax.set_ylim((15, -10)) ; ax.set_yticks(range(14))

# now, create an inset axis, in the upper right corner, with
# a zoom factor of two
zax = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 2, loc=1)

# plot again (PLOT AGAIN) the same stuff as before in the new axes
for i in range(14):
    start = 900-10*i
    zax.plot(t[1000:1500], -5*y[start:start+500]/(1+i*0.3)+i, 'k')

# and eventually specify the x, y limits for the zoomed plot,
# as well as the tick positions
zax.set_xlim((0.2, 0.7)) ; zax.set_xticks((0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7))
zax.set_ylim((1, -6)) ; zax.set_yticks([1]+[-i*0.5 for i in range(12)]) ;

# that's all folks
plt.show()
```

[image: my result]

Comment: if i increase my zoom factor, the zoomed in plot gets bigger and bigger - can i increase the zoom factor but force the built-in plot to always be the same size?

Comment: @CB95 if you increment the zoom factor AND you do not change the x, y limits, then the size of `zax` NECESSARILY has to increase ፨ on the other hand, if you increment the zoom factor and accordingly change the axes limits (decreasing the lengths) you have the equivalent of zooming in. ፨፨፨፨፨፨ E.G., if you use a zoom factor of 4 (double it) to have the same dimensions as before you have to reduce the spans of both axes to half.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research I found a method that should be exactly what you are looking for using the `inset_axes` method of matplotlib, you can find a nice working example in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#insetlocator). I hope it helps, I would have tried to apply it to your code, but without the data you used to plot there wasn't much I could do.

As you can find in the docs this method will allow you to do something as shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: dear Zulu - I have tried it with inset axes , but it didn't work! how would you apply it? even if you don't know the data now, I can adjust the zoom factor etc. myself - the x-axis shows the time in milliseconds and the y-axis the voltage per compartment, where each line represents one compartment

Comment: It is difficult to understand why `inset_axes` should not provide your desired result. Please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how you tried to implement this strategy and describe how the output differed from your expectations.

Comment: This is what inset_axes is meant to do, so if it “didn’t work” it would be helpful to know why.

Comment: in reality this is a plot that consists of many individual plots - plt.plot is generated depending on the number of compartments_to_plot. I just don't know how to place the zoom_inset_axis? how to create a subplot from plt.plot in the loop?